# Is there a quick way of renaming a file in Sublime Text 2?

Tags: sublimetext2

I'm quite frequently finding myself needing to rename a file that's deep in a sub directory somewhere and it's a pain having to expand the folders using the sidebar manually to be able to right click and rename.

Does anyone know of a quicker way of doing this? maybe some kind of extension that expands the folder sidebar to the current file you're working with?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Going to plug one of my plugins here, though it'll do what you want. https://github.com/skuroda/Sublime-AdvancedNewFile. Take a look at `ANF: Rename File` int he command palette. You can create a keybinding if necessary. Note that right now there is a bug with ST2 and Windows, that I'll fix a bit later today. I have what I believe will work on the dev branch of the plugin, just need to test it before I pull it into the master branch.